# Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dataSource"

Tags: java, spring

i am showing data from database. but Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dataSource" this error showing

servlet.xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

index.jsp file

```
<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="dataSource">
    select id, name, email, website from user
</sql:query>


<c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
    id: ${row.id}<br />
    Name: ${row.name}<br />
    Email: ${row.email}<br />
    Website: ${row.website}<br />
</c:forEach>
```

add jar file

```
spring-jdbc-5.0.2
mysql-connector-java-5.0.2
```

Comment: Seems that the JVM is not loading the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.2.jar` properly. How did you add it?

Comment: I am just paste the mysql-connector-java-5.0.2.jar file into the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are added in the lib folder, make an entry in the .classpath file so that it can able to run

```
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/resources/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.2.jar"/>
```

If you are packaging it as a jar using mvn, you need to make this entry in the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.2</version>
     <systemPath>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.2.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or manually download the `.jar` file from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and add it to your dependecy package.